# Conversion Of Map Location To String

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, bing-maps, mobile-application

Below is the code i am running with all other.. Its running perfectly adn its showing all the desired locations on map.
But what i want now is to store all the marked locations in such a way that i can show them as   a list on a new page.
I am not able to retrieve the resulted location from map in the form of some string or may be something else which can be displayed as a list ...

```
       private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {

        MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
        string search = "Coffee";
        mapsTask.SearchTerm = search;
        mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
        mapsTask.Show(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MapsTask` does not return any information.

If you're looking to get Points of Interest for a given location, you may have to use an external service such as the [HERE Places API](http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/).